# Increase/decrease text size of webpage using click() method

Tags: jquery, html, css

Wanting to increase and decrease the font size of an entire webpage using clickable links.  I have the links placed into the HTML, however, I am struggling with the jQuery side of things.

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#linkIncrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('increase');
  });
  $('#linkDecrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('decrease');
  });

  function modifyFontSize(flag) {
    var divElement = $('.body');
    var currentFontSize = parseInt(divElement.css('font-size'));
    if (flag == 'increase') currentFontSize += 3;
    else if (flag == 'decrease') currentFontSize -= 3;
    else currentFontSize = 16;
    divElement.css('font-size', currentFontSize);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d2eaf2;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Font-Size:
  <a id="linkIncrease" href="#">Increase</a>
  <a id="linkDecrease" href="#">Decrease</a>
  <a id="linkReset" href="#">Reset</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feeling very frustrated!

Comment: this is an awesome problem

Comment: You have a typo `var divElement = $('.body');` should be `var divElement = $('body');`

Comment: Extra suggestion: If you change the font-size on the html element instead, and style everything's font-sizes using rem's, they will scale with the increased or decreased font-size! 1rem = current html's font-size

Answer (score 1):

```js
var FirstSize=parseInt($("body").css("font-size"),10);
$(".ChangeFont span:last-child").html(FirstSize+"px");
$(".ChangeFont a").on("click",function(){
   var ds =parseInt($(this).attr("data-size"));
   $("body").css("font-size",(ds==0?FirstSize:parseInt($("body").css("font-size"),10)+ds));
   $(".ChangeFont span:last-child").html($("body").css("font-size"));
});
```

```css
body{background-color: #d2eaf2;}
.ChangeFont{display:flex}
.ChangeFont *{font-size:16px!important;}
.ChangeFont a{
padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
margin:5px;
border:1px solid lightgray;
cursor:pointer;
user-select: none; 
 background-color: #fff;
 min-width: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius:5px;
}
.ChangeFont a:hover{background-color:#eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ChangeFont">
 <a data-size="1">&#10010;</a>
 <a data-size="-1">&#9866;</a>
 <a data-size="0">&#8635;</a>
 <span>Font Size: </span> <span> </span>
</div>
<p>The chart below assumes you're starting at age 22 with zero dollars invested. It also assumes a 6 percent average annual investment return and various annual salaries.
Keep in mind that the chart does not factor in inflation or salary increases.
Here's how much you would have to set aside to have $1 million by age 50 if you earn:
$40,000: 34.6 percent of your income
$60,000: 23 percent of your income
$80,000: 17.3 percent of your income
$100,000: 13.8 percent of your income
$120,000: 11.5 percent of your income
"There's no doubt that trying to save $1 million in less than 30 years on a $40,000 income is going to be a real challenge," NerdWallet's investing and retirement specialist Andrea Coombes tells CNBC Make It. "Still, the amount you can save is directly tied to how much you spend, so if you can reduce spending enough to save 35 percent of your income, more power to you."</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This setFontSize function will allow you to set an arbitrary font size to an arbitrary CSS-selector

```
    var sheet = document.createElement('style');

    function setFontSize(selector, px) {
        sheet.innerHTML = selector + " { font-size: " + px + "px;}";
       // remove the previously-added styleSheet if present
       try {document.body.removeChild(sheet);} catch(e) {}
       document.body.appendChild(sheet);
    }

    var fontSize = 10;

    $('#linkIncrease').click(function () {
        fontSize += 3;
        setFontSize('body', fontSize);
    }
    );
    $('#linkDecrease').click(function () {
        fontSize -= 3;
        setFontSize('body', fontSize);
    }
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ora80f6/

Answer (score 0):

What is the result if you add a unit to the size calculated?
divElement.css('font-size', '' + currentFontSize + 'px')

Moreover, remove the '.' to retrieve divElement if it corresponds to a body element ('.' to use if the class of your div is 'body').

Answer (score 0):

You have  a mismatched jquery selector.
You forgot to call the function for the reset too...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#linkIncrease').click(function () {
            modifyFontSize('increase');
        }
        );
        $('#linkDecrease').click(function () {
            modifyFontSize('decrease');
        }
        );
        $('#linkReset').click(function () {
            modifyFontSize('reset');
        }
        );

            function modifyFontSize(flag) {
            var divElement=$('body');
            var currentFontSize=parseInt($("body").css('font-size'));

            if (flag=='increase')  
            currentFontSize +=3;
            else if 
            (flag=='decrease') currentFontSize -=3;        
            else  currentFontSize=16;

            divElement.css("fontSize", currentFontSize);
        }
    }
    );
```

This should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/ewn0Lnog/1/

Pericularly: 
`divElement = $('.body');` "body" it's not a class, it's:

```
divElement = $('body');
```